# Order the rows of a MySQL result based on a "next_id" field

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I'm currently working with a database table that is structured as follows:

```
 ______________________________
|  id  |  content  |  next_id  |
|------|-----------|-----------|
|  1   |  (value)  |     4     |
|  2   |  (value)  |     1     |
|  3   |  (value)  |   (NULL)  |
|  4   |  (value)  |     3     |
 ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

The value of the `next_id` field defines the id of the row of data that should follow it. A value of `NULL` means that no row follows it.

Is there a way I can query the database in such a way that in the resulting rows will be ordered using this method? For example, in the case I gave above, the rows should be returned ordered so that the ids are in this order: `2`, `1`, `4`, `3`. I'm looking for a solution that can do this regardless of the number of rows in this sequence.

I know that it is possible to reorder the results after retrieving them from the database (using the programming language I'm working with), but I'm hoping that there is a way that I can do it in SQL.

Comment: This is very much like nesting with an indefinite level depth.

Comment: Use a procedure or your programming language.

Comment: Seems to me you need to convert your data structure to use nested sets, then this sort of query would be easier.

Comment: What sort of constraints are in place? I.e., can I have `(1,2)` and `(2,1)`? What happens if I have `(1,4)`,`(4,2)` and `(2,1)`?

Comment: @Thomas you can assume that the data in the database is well-formed; i.e., there should be no circular references as you've given in your example.

Comment: @Timothy Armstrong - Be wary of such an assumption. That the existing data does not have any circular references is far different than the database specifically preventing them. If it is possible that they could exist, one day they will.

Comment: @Timothy Armstrong - How many levels of depth are possible? E.g., your OP, there are three: 2 to 1, 1 to 4, 4 to 3. Is it that there could be an unlimited levels of depth?

Comment: @Thomas I'm not sure how I could make the database prevent them from being created; however, the code which inserts the data into the database ensures that this does not happen (the only way it could happen is if data were entered manually).

Comment: @Thomas I am looking to support unlimited depth, as stated in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a solution without as many self-joins as you have rows. Instead I would build a nested set out of it in a temp table using push down stack algorithm and then retrieve a full tree.

Answer (score 0):

I've got something that's close.

```
/*one select to init the @next variable to the first row*/
select @next:= id from table1 order by isnull(next_id) asc, next_id asc limit 1;


select distinct a.id, a.next_id from table1 b
  inner join
  (
    select @rank:= id as id, @next:= next_id as next_id from table1
    where id = @next
  ) a
  on (b.id = b.id);
```

This outputs

```
+----+---------+
| id | next_id |
+----+---------+
| 2  | 1       |
| 1  | 4       |
```

And then stops. If only I could find a way for it to continue....

Anyway this sort of force feeding values into a query is dodgy enough when doing ranking, let alone this sort of stuff, so maybe I'm going down a dead end.